# Error: this.style is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for my noobish question just started learning javascript.

So I want to make function that hides `slika[0]`.

```
function hide() {
  this.style.display ='none';
};        

slika[0] = setTimeout(hide, 4000);
```

And the error is:

```
TypeError: this.style is undefined  
this.style.display ='none';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `hide`, `this` would be the `window` object and `window` object doesn't have `style` attribute. That is why you get

```
this.style is undefined
```

If you wanted to hide `slika[0]`, then you should [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the `hide` function with `slika[0]`, like this

```
setTimeout(hide.bind(slika[0]), 4000);
```

Now, you have bound the `slika[0]` to `hide` function. So, when `hide` is invoked, `this` will refer `slika[0]`, and it will set the display style to `none`.

If you want a generic function, you can simply accept the object as a parameter, like this

```
function hideObject(object) {
    object.style.display ='none';
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. But what should proper function be without changes in slika[0]? So when i call hide() i hides that element?

Comment: @user3477366 You are hiding after some time right? So, this would be the preferred way I believe.

Comment: Actually , i am trying to make picture slider and slika[0] is first <li>. So I'm trying to put 4 pictures in one position and then they just disappear and that is my first slider :D . So i make it work by creating 4 same functions (slika[0].style.display)(slika[1],slika[2] etc. But i want to make one function that when called it hides element that called. Sorry for bad explanation of problem.

Comment: @user3477366 Then you don't need timing?

Comment: Well, I don't have good logic yet , but practicing with this.

Comment: @user3477366 Check the updated answer for a generic function.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong with this answer.